# UnsatisfiedLinkError using Box2d libgdx for android

Tags: android, box2d, libgdx

I am trying to use the libGDX box2d wrapper, but I do not want to use the the full libGDX game engine, because I already have my game implemented and now I want to add some physics.

So, I downloaded the libGDX libraries and put them in build path.

I see the following error:

```
UnsatisfiedLinkError at com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World.newWorld(Native Method)
at com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World.<init>(World.java:101)
at org.anddev.andengine.extension.physics.box2d.PhysicsWorld.<init>(PhysicsWorld.java:61)
at org.anddev.andengine.extension.physics.box2d.PhysicsWorld.<init>(PhysicsWorld.java:57)
```

What can I do?

Comment: there is an UnsatisfiedLinkError and


 at com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World.newWorld(Native Method) at com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World.(World.java:101) at org.anddev.andengine.extension.physics.box2d.PhysicsWorld.(PhysicsWorld.java:61) at org.anddev.andengine.extension.physics.box2d.PhysicsWorld.(PhysicsWorld.java:57)

Comment: if anybody has this problem, i have solverd it: with this post found in another forum: import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxNativesLoader;
GdxNativesLoader.load(); 

Use this before you do anything. make sure you have gdx.jar and gdx-natives.jar in your project. Useful if you just want to use the physics library without anything else from libgdx. I use it on the server side.

Comment: @seipey, could you add your solution as a real 'answer' on this question?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I use this code from google [discussion](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/issues/detail?id=5) and it's working fine at my side.

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxNativesLoader;
GdxNativesLoader.load();
```

**Use this before you do anything. make sure you have `gdx.jar` and `gdx-natives.jar` in your project.**

Comment: Unspecified token

Answer (score 0):

This error will happen if you assign an instance during a World property declaration, keeping an empty declaration and assigning the new instance on the App create() method should fix it.